# Visual Studio 2017 Encapsulate Field - how to get the old format back?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So let's say I want to encapsulate the field with the good ol' Edit->Refactor->Encapsulate field, since it saves quite a bit of time:

```
private GameSettings gameSettings;
```

In Visual Studio 2015, I would get:

```
public GameSettings GameSettings
   {
      get
      {
         return gameSettings;
      }
      set
      {
         gameSettings = value;
      }
}
```

But with Visual Studio 2017 I get:

```
internal GameSettings GameSettings { get => gameSettings; set => gameSettings = value; }
```

Is there any way I can make it generate the old style? It looks wrong to have half the properties in one style and half in another...

Comment: 1.- http://imgur.com/kPw0S93 2.- http://imgur.com/MWT7YGd Hope it helps since my VS is not in english.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know this thread is old, but the answer can help anyone else...

You can go to Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > General and change "Use expression body for accessors" to "Never". So you'll get the old style.

Comment: And a very late "Thank you, this is exactly what I needed" from me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try messing around with the snippets:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\EncapsulateField.snippet"
```

Comment: The weird thing is that if I go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\EncapsulateField.snippet the file contains:

`<![CDATA[

$modifier$ $type$ $name$
{
  get { return $field$; }
  set { $field$ = value; }
}]]>`

Comment: Refactorings and Snippets are two different systems.  The refactoring is done programmatically via Roslyn, and I doubt you can change it from any kind of template. To use the snippet, type `prop` and hit `Tab` twice to expand it.

Comment: idk about this, but I'm gonna use the old Visual Studio until they revert back to the old refactoring format. I have to waste so many time to retype these fuckers!